# How to create pandas dataframe variable/column based on two or more other variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, e.g.:

```
Col1 Col2
A     1 
B     2
C     3
```

I understand how to create a Col3 based on say the value of Col2:

```
df['Col3'] = (df['Col2'] <= 1).astype(int)
```

But ... How about if the new column was based on two variables, as in (pseudocode here):

```
if Col2=1 and Col3=1 then Col4='X'
else if Col2=1 and Col3=2 then Col4='Y'
else Col4='Z'
```

how would that be achieved? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Col4'] = np.where((df['Col2'] == 1) & (df['Col3'] == 1), 'X', 
             np.where((df['Col2'] == 1) & (df['Col3'] == 2), 'Y', 'Z'))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3}, 
                   'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 
                   'Col3': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}})
print (df)

  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A     1     1
1    B     1     2
2    C     3     4

df['Col4'] = np.where( (df['Col2'] == 1) & (df['Col3'] == 1), 'X', 
             np.where((df['Col2'] == 1) & (df['Col3'] == 2), 'Y', 'Z'))

print (df)
  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
0    A     1     1    X
1    B     1     2    Y
2    C     3     4    Z
```

---

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for fill `NaN` all other values:

```
df.loc[ (df['Col2'] == 1) & (df['Col3'] == 1) , 'Col4'] =  'X'
df.loc[ (df['Col2'] == 1) & (df['Col3'] == 2) , 'Col4'] =  'Y'
df['Col4'] = df['Col4'].fillna('Z')

print (df)
  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
0    A     1     1    X
1    B     1     2    Y
2    C     3     4    Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the column with your final `else` value (e.g. `Z`) and then check each condition:

```
df['Col4'] = 'Z'
df.loc[(df.Col1 == 1) & (df.Col3 == 1), 'Col4'] = 'X'
df.loc[(df.Col2 == 1) & (df.Col3 == 2), 'Col4'] = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thanks. this and the previous answers work really well.